# Whether or not to use an interface in the given code?

Tags: java, interface

I have the following code:

```
public class TestClass extends NewClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    }

    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}

interface I {
    void doSomething();
}

abstract class NewClass implements I {
    // public abstract void doSomething();  // put doSomething() here and remove the interface or put doSomething() in the interface and implement it?

    public void myFunc() {
        doSomething();
    }

}
```

Now my question is : should I put the method doSomething() in the abstract class or should i create a seperate interface and put the method there and make my abstract class implement it?. Which is a good design?. Please note that, the No-interface approach is already being used in the code base but I still wonder if putting doSomething() in an interface and implementing the interface would be better. Or should I follow the philosophy of - "Dont create a class/interface just because you can, create it if you must".?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JLS states that if all methods in your abstract class are abstract then it is better to use interface rather than abstract classes.

If you have non abstract methods then you have to go with abstract classes because methods declared in interfaces are implicitly `public` and `abstract`. As for your `doSomething();` method you can define it either way -`abstract` or non `abstract`. If it is abstract first concrete subclass should implement it. If it is non abstract you can still override your method.

Comment: No.. I have non-abstract methods as well..

Comment: Sound logical, because you have multiple inheritance from interfaces in Java. But you can only inherit from one Abstract Super Class.

Comment: Hmmm, in Java 8 you can provide default implementation in interfaces of course : http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/java-8-explained-default-methods/

Comment: yeah in that case you can go for `abstract class`. Updated the answer with same.

Comment: Keep all your abstract methods in interface and non abstract methods in abstract class and extend abstract class and implement the interface for your class

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the case in question, but generally speaking, if the method (or group of methods) makes logical sense by itself without the context of the abstract class, it's a good idea to use an interface, even if you also provide an abstract class with some skeleton (or empty) implementations. This gives testers and other implementers freedom to handle the contract in different ways than you'd anticipated.

For a good example of this pattern, see the Java Collections framework. The main collection interfaces all have accompanying `Abstract*` classes for ease of implementation, but there's no requirement that the implementations use those classes, and special-purpose ones (like ORM frameworks) often work directly with the interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

This really sounds like a matter of opinion - there are some other questions to ask that may help you decide:

- Do you have anything else that will implement interface `I`? If not, perhaps the interface doesn't serve a purpose, and isn't necessary.
- Does your abstract class have any real functions in it? If not, perhaps it should be completely an interface.

Comment: No other classes implement this interface.. I was thinking of creating the interface solely for convenience.

Comment: What kind of convenience does it provide, exactly? It's only convenient if you might have another implementation other than your abstract class and it's hierarchy.

Comment: Makes perfect sense.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Java supports 3 kinds of constructs:

1. **Class** - fully implemented (ie; You have to provide body to all the functions defined in class)
2. **Abstract Class** - Partially implemented, partially unimplemented (It can have some methods which are left for the child classes to implement in order to provide more flexibility)
3. **Interface** - Fully unimplemented. (Implementation classes are responsible for providing bodies

Now it totally depends on your requirement.

**Interfaces** are also used as contracts, when you want to define the rule and implementation is left to users.

**Abstract classes** are useful in conditions when there are some common functionality among classes extending it.

Answer (score 0):

As a concept :

1. Use abstract classes and inheritance if you can make the statement
   "Class A is a class B".  For example you can say, **Inspiron N5010
   is a Laptop**
2. Use interfaces if you can make the statement "A is capable of
   [doing] as", or also, abstract for what a class is, interface for
   what a class can do. for example, A **Inspiron N5010 laptop is
   capable of being Dell**